# in Jupyter Notebook ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, importerror

I installed plotly library using anaconda prompt and it is appearing in my conda list. I can use it in Spyder but when i Import it in my Jupyter Notebook it Shows an Import error.

---

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-182e2a6c8e92> in <module>
----> 1 import plotly as py

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'
```

But in my conda list it is seen as this.

```
plotly                    3.10.0                     py_0    conda-forge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Jupyter Notebook is probably not part of the Anaconda. Hence it is not recognising packages installed through Anaconda.

**Solution 1**
install Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda and try to run notebooks from there. When you will import plotly  there it will be imported.

**Solution 2**
install pip. Here's how: [how to install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)
Then use `pip install plotly` in command prompt.
You will be able to import plotly in Jupyter now.

Feel free to comment if you have any questions.

Comment: I  already have pip. But it worked. Again i installed plotly by creating a venv in conda. It is working now.