# JetBrains DataSpell ModuleNotFoundError error when package is installed

Tags: python, pycharm, modulenotfounderror, prophet, dataspell

I use `ipynb`-file. When I try to import `prophet` library I get this:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prophet'.

But this package is installed and it is in my current environment. Jupyter server's interpreter have `prophet` library. When I move cursor to name of library, DataSpell shows its info:

[image: screenshot]

If I execute `from prophet import Prophet` in python console everything is OK! I think problem is in Jupyter notebook, but can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this recently.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60885167/2461398) set me on the right track.

`jupyter` was also installed in one of my default Ubuntu python environments, and DataSpell was spinning up a server using *that* binary instead of the one installed in the environment I'd created in DataSpell.

(As a coincidence, that default environment also had common packages like `pandas` installed, so I didn't run into this till I installed a package in the DataSpell-managed environment that *wasn't* already in my Ubuntu default python environment.)

- I found the default jupyter binary: `which jupyter`.
- Inspected the script: `nano /home/<user>/.local/bin/jupyter`
- Saw the python environment it was installed in: `#!/usr/bin/python3.8` at the top of the script
- Uninstalled `jupyter` from that environment: `python3.8 -m pip uninstall jupyter`

And then DataSpell used the correct `jupyter` binary (and all imports worked fine).

Answer (score 0):

I did **SOLVE** it in a simpler way using the following steps:

1. Run your Jupyter Notebook from windows start (I have anaconda).
2. From Jupyter CMD copy the 2nd link look similar to this:
   http://127.0.0.2:8890/?token=f1204144....
3. In Dataspell Go to File->Add Jupyter Connection-> Select "Connect to
   Jupyter server using URL" and Paste the copied link in step 2.
   A folder will be appeared after this open your code "notebook" from that folder.

**Enjoy!**

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have already installed the package/s beforehand. The next thing to do is to configure the right interpreter. For that you would have to follow the official documentation
[Set up a working environment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dataspell/configuring-python-interpreter.html) .

In my case, I had a working anaconda environment which was working fine on Jupyter Notebook but not in DataSpell, even after the configuration.

Then I tried **Files -> Invalidate Caches** in IDE's toolbar.

This will remove the internal DataSpell cached files and restart the app and that was enough for me. Everything started working fine after that.